# How to return the records with the earliest time stamp and the latest timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that pulls the users clock in and clock out time.  What i'm looking to do is return only the results of the FIRST clock in time and the LAST clock out time.

My query is:

```
SELECT
   lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
   dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
   fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM            
   TimeClock
WHERE        
   (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

Comment: My query returns all 50 employees who clocked in and out.  I want to return the employee who was first to clock in for a specific date, and the last employee who was last to clock out for the specific date.

Comment: Just an observation, why the l, s, dt, f prefixes? What happens when you change a datetime column to smalldatetime or float to decimal? I suggest you stop using metadata prefixes on your columns, they will only lead to confusion later.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with the `row_number` function:

```
SELECT lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
       dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
       fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM (select tc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(dtTimeIn as date) order by dtTimeIn) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(dtTimeIn as date) order by dtTimeIn desc) as seqnum_desc
     from TimeClock tc
     WHERE (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
    ) tc
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1
```

I am assuming that dtTimeIn contains both the date and the time that you are looking for.

Comment: This says invalid table tc

Comment: I left out the alias in the subquery.

Comment: you're also calling for columns of the subquery prior to giving it an alias

Comment: @Shmewnix uh, what are you talking about with your last comment? SELECT is parsed last. How do you propose you select columns from the alias without defining the alias *after*?

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `rank()`;

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, 
       sUpdatedBy, dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, 
       dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, fOTHours, dblOTLabor, 
       dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeIn) rk1, --earliest record gets 1
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC) rk2 --latest record gets 1

    FROM  TimeClock
    WHERE (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND 
      (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
) A
WHERE rk1=1 OR rk2=1
```

**Edit (1):** Edited with `Partitian by` *sDept*

**Edit (2):** Edited removed `Partitian by` *sDept* again.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the "department" filter.

Comment: @Shmewnix: `(sDept IN ('1', '2', '3')` is as per your `WHERE` clause. I haven't removed or added filters.

Comment: Correct, however for some reason, this grabs an incorrect department (the first user to clock in, instead of the first user to clock in with the specified department)

Comment: @Shmewnix: What you need is to add `PARTITION BY sDept` for `Rank()`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: This returns 6 results.  I'm looking for 2 results.  Just the time in (first one to punch in within the departments listed above, and the last one out, listed in the departments listed above.)

Comment: @Shmewnix: **That was what I had before**. then you said you want to filter by `sDept`. Please be clear. Remove the partition if not needed. if you partition each dept brings 2 rows and 6 in total for 3 dept.

Comment: I believe I was clear... I'm looking for the first person to punch-in, in one of the 3 departments listed above and the LAST person to punch out in one of the departments above.  The first problem with your query was it was listing the FIRST person to punch-in regardless of department.  Your edited query displays 6 results... (all clock in and out of the departments above) which is what my initial query does... so I'm back to square one...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21307/discussion-between-kaf-and-shmewnix)

Comment: If you change this to remove the entire "Partition BY SDEPT" on each line, I can accept this as the answer.  You were returning the first in and first out of EACH department.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to perform this:

```
SELECT
   lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
   dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
   fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM TimeClock c
LEFT JOIN
(
    select MIN(dtTimeIn) MindtTimeIn, CAST(dtTimeIn as DATE) dt
    from timeclock
    group by CAST(dtTimeIn as DATE)
) MinEmp
    on c.dtTimeIn = MinEmp.MindtTimeIn
    and CAST(c.dtTimeIn as DATE) = MinEmp.dt
LEFT JOIN
(
    select MAX(dtTimeOut) MaxdtTimeOut, CAST(dtTimeOut as DATE) dt
    from timeclock
    group by CAST(dtTimeOut as DATE)
) MaxEmp
    on c.dtTimeOut = MaxEmp.MaxdtTimeOut
    and CAST(c.dtTimeOut as DATE) = MaxEmp.dt
WHERE (dtTimeIn > @startdate) 
    AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) 
    AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

If you are not using SQL Server 2008+, then you do not have the `DATE` datatype so you can use:

```
SELECT
   lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
   dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
   fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM TimeClock c
LEFT JOIN
(
    select MIN(dtTimeIn) MindtTimeIn, Convert(char(10), dtTimeIn, 120) dt
    from timeclock
    group by Convert(char(10), dtTimeIn, 120)
) MinEmp
    on c.dtTimeIn = MinEmp.MindtTimeIn
    and Convert(char(10), c.dtTimeIn, 120) = MinEmp.dt
LEFT JOIN
(
    select MAX(dtTimeOut) MaxdtTimeOut, Convert(char(10), dtTimeOut, 120) dt
    from timeclock
    group by Convert(char(10), dtTimeOut, 120
) MaxEmp
    on c.dtTimeOut = MaxEmp.MaxdtTimeOut
    and Convert(char(10), c.dtTimeOut, 120 = MaxEmp.dt
WHERE (dtTimeIn > @startdate) 
    AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) 
    AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

Comment: @Shmewnix what version of SQL Server? If you are not using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use my second version of the query

Comment: If you run one of the subqueries does it work?  If not what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do:

```
SELECT [] FROM [] WHERE [] AND rownum = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT [] FROM [] WHERE [] AND rownum = 1 ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

There's probably a better way to do that but this will get you your answer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you add a ORDER BY dtTimeIn ASC and limit the amount of rows with TOP 1 it will return the first to clock in. If you add ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC and limit the amount of rows with TOP 1 it will show you the last to clock out. You just need to do a union of those 2 queries.

I haven't tried it but it could look like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  (

SELECT
   lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
   dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
   fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM            
   TimeClock
WHERE        
   (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
ORDER BY dtTimeIn ASC
)

UNION 

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (

SELECT
   lRecordID, lEmployeeID, dtTimeIn, dtTimeOut, sEnteredBy, sUpdatedBy, 
   dtUpdated, sDept, fHoursWorked, lDeptID, dblHourlyWage, fRegHours, dblRegLabor, 
   fOTHours, dblOTLabor, dtTimePunchIn, dtTimePunchOut, fPunchedHours
FROM            
   TimeClock
WHERE        
   (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept IN ('1', '2', '3'))
ORDER BY dtTimeOut DESC

)
```

Comment: Seems redundant in any case... though I was not the down-voter FWIW.

Comment: Would the approach work? I believe it would. I have seen other approaches here which use functions that are not supported on all SQL Server versions and may slow down result set.

Comment: I don't see any functions on this page not supported on 2005+, and it's usually a safe assumption that the OP is not on SQL Server 7.0 or 2000 unless they say so. I also don't see any answers that will perform worse than what you have, but I would prefer those because I'd be typing less (and making fewer fixes if I later have to change, say, the select list).

Comment: I use SQL Server 2000 and so would a few users coming here so the answer is still valid. The OP has down voted me but is still struggling with the other queries. There is less typing involved because it is mostly a copy/paste of the original query. Your last point is valid: 'making fewer fixes'.

Comment: IMHO you would only use 2000-specific syntax if you are using 2000 specifically. In general avoiding 2005 syntax is like avoiding lead-free gasoline... such an answer is only going to be useful for so long, and that utility will decrease with every passing day. Also the DRY principle doesn't just apply to making fixes. What about the people who have to read that code and determine, character by character, that both subqueries are actually identical?

Comment: Actually looking closer your syntax is not even correct since you can't have ORDER BY in the subqueries without TOP. You need to move the TOP 1 to inside each subquery. I still find this wastefully redundant. Since there is a PK (`lRecordID`) you can certainly find the top and bottom row for a specific day and then reference all the other columns you need *once*, and you can do that with 2000 syntax.